# Include column from a :belongs_to association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Product model

```
Class Product < ActiveRecord::Base  
    belongs_to :product_group  
end
```

ProductGroup model

```
Class ProductGroup < ActiveRecord::Base  
    has_many :products  
end
```

Is the a way to declare a shortcut for `product.product_group.name` as `product.name`,
and have `product_group.name` included in `product.to_json` as `name` whenever a Product is converted to json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question: create a `name` method in `Product`

```
def name
  product_group.name
end
```

As for your second question, you can customize `as_json`, also in your `Product` model. Something like this should work.

```
def as_json(options = {})
  super.merge({ name: name })
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I was too busy looking for rails magic I forgot to look at the simple way of doing it.

Comment: `super.merge({ name: name })` added name alongside store_product `{"store_product" => {}, "name" => 'name'}` using `super["store_product"].merge({name: name})` is better